# error: LexToken(>,'>',34,890) error: LexToken(:,':',37,1148) on PLYJ

Tags: java, django, parsing, ply

I am using PlyJ parser to parse a Java file to get package name and method names from that file. It is doing a good job except sometimes it shows me

> error: LexToken(>,'>',34,890) error: LexToken(:,':',37,1148)

I don't know why do I see this one? I am parsing thousands of files, so I can't really tell where do I see this error exactly. My major concern is what this error is all about and should I worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicates that there was something which the grammar couldn't handle. The tuple shown contains the erroneous token, and its line number and character offset.

"Erroneous" means that the indicated token was where the syntax error was noted, because it does not fit any grammar production possible at that point. The actual error may be prior to that point, but it's a good place to start looking.

It might also indicate that the input uses a grammatical feature not implemented by the grammar.

Comment: I had suspected the same thing. I am using PlyJ parser to parse Java files via python as I said above. I will need to see if that makes entire parsing file fail or it spits out error and move on. Thank you for your clarification. Didn't find anything simpler as compared to this explanation.